# PCA line keeping with laser scan data?

Tags: c++, ros, pca, lidar

Im trying to detect the corridor area (walls)  using 2D Lidar while robot is moving. I would like to use PCA (Principle Component Analysis ) and ROS . I didnt find any examples in ROS using laser scan data and PCA. I find an  ROS example of OpenCV using PCA. So this is the code

```
 using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
        
    vector<Point2d> getOrientation(vector<Point> &pts, Mat &img) //Taking address of pointers from main() as arugments and storing them
    {
        //if (pts.size() == 0) return false;
    
        //First the data need to be arranged in a matrix with size n x 2, where n is the number of data points we have. Then we can perform that PCA analysis. The calculated mean (i.e. center of mass) is stored in the "pos" variable and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues are stored in the corresponding std::vector’s.
    
        //Construct a buffer called data_pts used by the pca analysis
        Mat data_pts = Mat(pts.size(), 2, CV_64FC1); //pts.size() rows, 2 columns, matrix type will be CV_64FC1(Type to hold inputs of "double")
        for (int i = 0; i < data_pts.rows; ++i)
        {
            data_pts.at<double>(i, 0) = pts[i].x;
            data_pts.at<double>(i, 1) = pts[i].y;
        }
    
    
        //Perform PCA analysis. Principal Component Analysis allows us to find the direction along which our data varies the most. In fact, the result of running PCA on the set of points in the diagram consist of 2 vectors called eigenvectors which are the principal components of the data set.
        PCA pca_analysis(data_pts, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);
    
        //Store the position of the object
        Point pos = Point(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 0),
                          pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 1));
    
        //Store the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
        vector<Point2d> eigen_vecs(2);
        vector<double> eigen_val(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            eigen_vecs[i] = Point2d(pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 0), pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 1));
    
            eigen_val[i] = pca_analysis.eigenvalues.at<double>(0, i);
        cout << "Eigen Vector: "<< eigen_vecs[i] << endl;
        cout << "Eigen Value: " << eigen_val[i] << endl;
        }
    
    
    // Find a way to acquire highest Eigen Value and the Vector Associated with it and find a way to pass it on to the motor controller(The Pic 24) 
        double valueMAX = *max_element(eigen_val.begin(), eigen_val.end());
        double index = find(eigen_val.begin(), eigen_val.end(), valueMAX) - eigen_val.begin();
    
        cout << "\nMax value is: " << valueMAX << endl;
        cout << "\nThe index of the largest value is: " << index << endl;
    
        vector<Point2d> correctVector(2);
        for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
        if(i == index)
        {
            correctVector[0] = eigen_vecs[i];
        }
        }
    
        cout <<" \nThe vector that corresponds with the value is: " << correctVector[0] << endl;
    
        float degrees = ((atan2(eigen_vecs[0].y, eigen_vecs[0].x) * 180) / 3.14159265);
        cout <<" \nThe degrees using ArcTangent of the vector(x,y) is: " << degrees << endl;
    
         //ros::Publisher vector_pub = node.advertise<std_msgs::String>("vector", 1000);
    
        // Draw the principal components, each eigenvector is multiplied by its eigenvalue and translated to the mean position.
        circle(img, pos, 3, CV_RGB(255, 0, 255), 2);
        line(img, pos, pos + 0.02 * Point(eigen_vecs[0].x * eigen_val[0], eigen_vecs[0].y * eigen_val[0]) , CV_RGB(255, 255, 0));
        line(img, pos, pos + 0.02 * Point(eigen_vecs[1].x * eigen_val[1], eigen_vecs[1].y * eigen_val[1]) , CV_RGB(0, 255, 255));
    
        //return degrees;
        return correctVector;
    }
     int main(int argc, char **argv)
     {
        VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from web cam/USB cam. (0) for webcam, (1) for USB.
    
        if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
        {
             cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
             return -1;
        }
    
      //Creating values for Hue, Saturation, and Value. Found that the color Red will be near 110-180 Hue, 60-255 Saturation, and 0-255 Value. This combination seems to pick up any red object i give it, as well as a few pink ones too. 
    
      int count = 0;
    
      int iLowH = 113;
      int iHighH = 179;
    
      int iLowS = 60; 
      int iHighS = 255;
    
      int iLowV = 0;
      int iHighV = 255;
    
    /**
       * The ros::init() function needs to see argc and argv so that it can perform
       * any ROS arguments and name remapping that were provided at the command line.
       * For programmatic remappings you can use a different version of init() which takes
       * remappings directly, but for most command-line programs, passing argc and argv is
       * the easiest way to do it.  The third argument to init() is the name of the node.
       *
       * You must call one of the versions of ros::init() before using any other
       * part of the ROS system.
    */
    
      // Initiate a new ROS node named "talker"
      ros::init(argc, argv,"OpenCV");
    
      /**
       * NodeHandle is the main access point to communications with the ROS system.
       * The first NodeHandle constructed will fully initialize this node, and the last
       * NodeHandle destructed will close down the node.
       */
    
      // creating a node handle: It is the reference assigned to a new node. EVERY NODE MUST HAVE A REFERENCE!
      ros::NodeHandle node;
    
    
    
    
    
        while (true)
        {
            Mat frame;
    
            bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video
    
             if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
            {
                 cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
                 break;
            }
    
       Mat imgHSV;
    
       cvtColor(frame, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from RBG to HSV
    
       Mat imgThresholded;
    
       inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image
    
      //morphological opening (remove small objects from the foreground)
      erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
      dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 
    
       //morphological closing (fill small holes in the foreground)
      dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 
      erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
    
     // Find all objects of interest, find all contours in the threshold image
            vector<vector<Point> > contours; //vector of vector points
            vector<Vec4i> hierarchy; // Vector of 4 interges
        vector<Point2d> result;
    
        //findContours essentially is tracing all continuous points caputured by the thresholding, I feel this gives accuracy to the upcoming Eigen analysis and also helps in detecting what is actually an object versus  what is not. The arguments for findingContours() is the following( binary image, contour retrieval mode, contour approximation method)
    
        findContours(imgThresholded, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    
            ros::Publisher vector_pub = node.advertise<std_msgs::UInt8MultiArray("vector", 1000); // THIS IS THE ERROR IN MY CODE, HOW DO I PUBLISH THE VECTOR OF TYPE vector<Point2d>!?!?
    
    
        // For each object
            for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
        {
    
            // Calculate its area of each countour
                double area = contourArea(contours[i]);
    
            // Ignore if too small or too large
                if (area < 1e2 || 1e5 < area) continue;
    
            // Draw the contour for visualisation purposes
                drawContours(frame, contours, i, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0); 
            count++;
            cout << "This is frame: " << count <<endl;
            //usleep(500000);
    
            result = getOrientation(contours[i], frame);
            cout<< "THE VECTOR BEING PASSED TO THE TOPIC IS: " << result << endl;
        }
    
    
       imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded); //show the thresholded image with Contours.
      imshow("Original", frame); //show the original image
    
            if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
           {
                cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
                break; 
           }
        }
       return 0;
    }
```

My question is how to modify the code so I can use /scan topic instead of image to perform PCA?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you keep the part that does the PCA, but delete the part that gets the points from the image?

Comment: yes so the part than get laser scan point how should be?